# Tensile stress, is the pressure given indicating just one side?

Tags: elasticity

I'm studying elasticity right now in my chemistry class, and I'm confused as to what exactly tensile stress (and maybe compression stress too) might mean. It's given in N/m^2. And you're stretching the material.

Is the cypher I'm given indicative of what's happening only one side? Indicative of the pulling force acting on one edge of the material?

Comment: Please get some minimal info by yourself before asking http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(mechanics)

Comment: I don't think that article really addresses my question. Nor does my textbook. There are some images that make me think it is the force applied on only one edge (even though there are really forces on both edges), but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you're stretching a material, I would have thought the stress was distributed throughout the material.

For example, if there is tension in a string, that tension is distributed throughout the matreial. By stretching it, the stress isn't only applied to 'one side', no matter where you pull the string from. As a result, the pressure should be 'felt' throughout the material, rather than just on the edge.

Comment: Yeah, but the cypher I'm given I think comes from a computer reading of the force that the machine applies on one end.

Comment: sure, the internal forces also act at the end, and there is where it is easier to measure it

Comment: if the material is being pulled from one end, it must be attached to something else in order for it to be pulled. so tension should act throughout the system, the point at which it is measured should be arbitrary (however pressure would change depending on whether the object was uniform in shape)